# Why aren't the homotopy group functors a generalized homology theory?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, functors

I am currently enrolled in an introductory course on algebraic topology.

In a recent research seminar at my home institution, it was stated that the homotopy group functors $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3, ...$ are not a generalized homology theory, and I'd like to know why.

I know that $\pi_n(X)$ consists of the homotopy classes of basepoint-preserving maps from $S^n$ into $X$, and I know of the four axioms (homotopy, exactness, excision, additivity) that need to be satisfied to define a generalized homology theory. What axiom isn't satisfied when trying to define a generalized homology theory via the homotopy group functors ?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically everything apart from the homotopy axiom falls apart. In any case notice that $\pi_0X$ is only a pointed set, and $\pi_1X$ is in general a non-abelian group. On the other hand you can replace $\pi_*$ with a very similar functor (namely the [stable homotopy groups](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+group+of+a+spectrum#definition)) and obtain a bona-fide homology theory.

Comment: I believe it is excision that fails, at least in general. There are theorems like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_excision_theorem) which give us when it holds.

Comment: you can take stable homotopy groups to get a reduced homology theory. This is basically a consequence of homotopy excision (blakers-massey)

Comment: @Tyrone Could you possibly provide a link to a source that proves the stable homotopy groups functor you'd mentioned yields a generalized homology theory ? If not, that's okay. Thanks for your comment !

Comment: Certainly. See Hatcher's book [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) $\S4.F$ *Spectra and Homology Theories*. It's such an important example that the relevant proposition appears after the first paragraph. You'll probably need to make reference to other parts of the book to understand the proof, but it's all in there if you have patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll note that homotopy groups do not even solely take values in groups since $\pi_0$ is a set. Even if we ignore $\pi_0$ they do not take values in abelian groups since $\pi_1$ may be noncommutative.

Let's suppose we ignore both of those issues. If the homotopy groups were a generalized homology theory, then they would have a suspension isomorphism. This would mean that the homotopy groups of $S^1$ would be the same as the shifted homotopy groups of $S^2$. However, $\pi_2(S^1)=0$ while $\pi_3 (S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$.

When one forces the suspension isomorphism to work for homotopy groups, one arrives at the stable homotopy groups $\pi_* ^s$ which do form a homology theory. This has the result of making the stable homotopy groups of $S^0$ very complicated, even though the homotopy groups of $S^0$ are trivial.